# Using Pytorch for list as features and list as target/label?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
X1 = 2
X2 = [1,2,3,4]
X3 = [6,7,8,9]
Y = [0.23, 5.4, 2.1, 3.0]
```

More specifically, I have this [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff5aG.png) . The last column is the label.

How do I use PyTorch for this problem?

I know it looks like multi-output regression problem but I am not sure. Can someone help, please?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but in both of the example mappings, all three elements have the same index in their respective lists, if that is the goal you might simply do this: Y[X1.index(1)], without further examples with different relative indices there is nothing we can do.

Comment: We normally have numeric value for features and label. But in this case, I have list values as features and labels

Comment: Are the lists of variable length? Are they unordered? If not, you can just encode each element of the list as its own variable.

Answer (score 0):

If (as implied in the screenshot) each of `X1`, `X2`, `X3` is of fixed length, then you can simply concatenate the inputs:

```py
X1 = torch.tensor([2])
X2 = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4])
X3 = torch.tensor([6,7,8,9])

features = torch.cat([X1, X2, X3])
```

As for the targets, this is as you say multi-output regression.